# Do you have additional examples of executing MySql with Wix?

Tags: mysql, windows-7, installation, wix

I'm still working on my Wix installer that includes replacing some MySql commands.

Specifically, I want the installer to run a script that creates a user, and then using that user, I want the installer to run a script that creates a database and creates tables.  (It seems that an installer should be able to do this.)

I posted earlier about the user, and haven't been able to figure that out yet.

So skipping that for a moment, let's assume that my user exists.  This user happens to *not* have a password.  Without the installer, the command I usually do to run my script that creates the database and tables is:

mysql --user=myname < thisismyscript.sql

This works fine - so I know my script works.

Two problems I see in the Wix, and I'm hoping someone can either explain, or post additional examples (I learn best by seeing others examples).

1) seems to be the lack of a password.

In the .wxs file, I have:

```
<util:User Id='SQLUser' Name='[SQLUSER]' />

<Component Id='SqlComponent' Guid='7B524167-D8CF-465E-AEE8-6B70CF712A3A' KeyPath='yes'>
<sql:SqlDatabase Id='SqlDatabase' Database='adatabase' User='SQLUser' Server='[SQLSERVER]'
                    CreateOnInstall='yes' DropOnUninstall='yes' ContinueOnError='yes'>
<sql:SqlScript Id='mynewdb' BinaryKey='mynewdb' ExecuteOnInstall='yes' />
</sql:SqlDatabase>
</Component>

<Binary Id='mynewdb' SourceFile='thisismyscript.sql' />

<Property Id='SQLUSER'>myname</Property>
<Property Id='SQLSERVER'>localhost</Property>
```

(this is all embeded in the right places in the .wxs file and the file compiles fine... it's just when I run the .msi, my database has not been created.)

The only way I was able to leave the password property blank was to add that Admin tag.  I'm not sure what to do here.

1. The second problem is that within the SQLComponent, I had to write down a database name, but of course, this database doesn't actually exist yet.  Is this a problem?  (I also tried creating the database manually, so that when the .msi ran it would already be there... but then nothing else happened)

I also ran msiexec with logging, and it appears that my sql script executes... there are no errors that I can see in the log.

Help? This really seems like something an installer should be able to do... and that I'm just doing something wrong...

Thanks in advance!

-Adeena

Comment: MSI does not allow properties with `""` value. You may want to consider removing the declaration of `SQLPASSWORD` property; if it is not defined, its value would be `""`.

Comment: So I just removed the SQLPASSWORD as suggested (and modified the wix code above to show you what it looks like now).  Candle and light ran fine, but when I went to install, it still didn't create my database...  :(

Comment: I have no ideas then. Could it be related to permission issues? I mean the script starts but fails to create a database because of _permission denied_. MSI verbose log will have the parameters which it started running your SQL script; maybe it will shed some light on the issue.

Comment: I just re-ran, making sure I created verbose log (using the command: msiexec /i myinstallpackage.msi /l*v mylogfile.txt).  Looking at the logfile, it appears that the mysql stuff executed properly! There's the init create database with an exit code of 1... and several sql executions with also an exit code of 1... am I not understanding the logfile contents?

Comment: Exit code 1 usually means a failure. You should try to run the command on the command line (batch file) and test the exit code.

Comment: Ugh - I didn't know that.  I'm taking a break from this for a couple days... for the moment, my install procedure has the user just doing the mysql stuff manually.  That's okay for my purposes right now, but I would eventually like to figure this out so I remove the risk of mistakes/typos by the user!  Thanks for your help!  :D

Comment: By the way, you can create Custom Actions to call `mysql` executable directly, just like you do in the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Neither WiX nor MSI has native support for MySQL.  InstallShield has MySQL support.

Comment: So if not MySQL, what flavor of SQL is referred to here:  http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson7.php

Comment: MSSQL - Microsoft SQL Server.  ( Remember, WiX is OSS but it's still from Microsoft so that would be their first and perhaps only priority. )

Comment: You might want to check out this third party extension http://code.dblock.org/Showpost.aspx?id=100